# Blurry viewport shading after updating to 2.93

Tags: 3d-view

On 2.92 I had no significant difference between viewport shading and render

Now the viewport looks unsaturated, foggy and blurry and simply can't be used to render preview anymore

Viewport:
[image: pic]

Render:
[image: pic]

`$ blender --version`

```
Color management: using fallback mode for management
Color management: Error could not find role data role.
Blender 2.93.0
        build date: 2021-06-04
        build time: 17:23:25
        build commit date: 2021-06-02
        build commit time: 13:05
        build hash: ddb2d7143899
        build platform: Linux
        build type: Release
        build c flags:  -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=implicit-function-declaration
 -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-c
har-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-s
trings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero 
-Wtype-limits -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wnonnull -Wabsolute-value -Wuninit
ialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit
-fallthrough=5 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-p
lt -fuse-ld=gold -fopenmp -std=gnu11 -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-stri
ct-aliasing -ffp-contract=off -msse2  
        build c++ flags:  -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-o
ffsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-d
iv-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-p
ragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wformat-signe
dness -Wrestrict -Wno-suggest-override -Wuninitialized -Wundef -Wmissing-declara
tions -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -I /usr/include/python3.9 -fuse-ld=gold -fopenmp 
-std=c++17 -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=
off -msse2  
        build link flags:  -Wl,--version-script='/build/blender/src/blender/sour
ce/creator/blender.map'
        build system: CMake
```

Comment: try disabling the denoise in the viewport..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If disabling denoise doesn't work as @Sanbaldo suggested try verifying your settings for color management in the cycles settings
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Lowlande52: Strangely, I don't have Filmic as option. Seems a bug: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/71110?project=5&string=blender